# React Native: How to build android app in Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am building an android app with Expo, but failed every time.
Here is my app.json

```
"expo": {
"name": "Imct",
"slug": "Imct",
"version": "1.0.0",
"orientation": "portrait",
"icon": "./src/asset/Logo/IMCT.png",
"splash": {
  "image": "./src/asset/Logo/imct2.png",
  "resizeMode": "contain",
  "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
},
"ios": {
  "supportsTablet": true,
  "bundleIdentifier": "com.isuzu.imct"
},
"android": {
  "versionCode": 2,
  "adaptiveIcon": {
    "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
    "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
  },
 
  "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
  "package": "com.isuzu.imct"
},
```

when I run

> expo build:android

I got the results is
[Screenshot 2022-03-17 104029](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO4V0.png)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please check you google-service.json file in that package name is same or different might be that's the issue. if different then you need to re-create google-service.json from firebase with same package name of your project.

Comment: It's not same. how can i re-create google-service.json from firebase? any guideline?

Comment: You can go into **firebase** and in your project **setting icon** show click after show pop-up in that click on **project setting** in that scroll down and you will see the your app and remove this app and re-create with the same package name.